# Test to see if differences between measurements are different across groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, paired-data

Here's a simplified version of my problem. I asked two people to guess the height of people walking by. The guesses were very different. I learned that sometimes estimators would sit and sometimes they would stand. I had them both stand up and make more height estimates. I want to know if the measurements between the two people were more similar to each other when they were both standing up.

Here's a reproducible example in R. `estimate1` and `estimate2` show the guess in inches from each of the two guessers. Each row reflects guesses about the height of the same person. The variable `position` shows if the guessers were in different body positions (sitting and standing) or the same position.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(327)

dta <- tibble(estimate1 = rnorm(n = 23, mean = 67, sd = 3))
dta$estimate2 <- dta$estimate1 * rnorm(nrow(dta), .8, .07)
dta <- mutate(dta, position = "different")

dta_post <- tibble(estimate1 = rnorm(n = 7, mean = 67, sd = 3))
dta_post$estimate2 <- dta_post$estimate1 * rnorm(nrow(dta_post), .9, .07)
dta_post <- mutate(dta_post, position = "same")

dta <- rbind(dta, dta_post)
rm(dta_post)
```

It would be easy to see if estimate2 changed after having both guessers stand...

`t.test(estimate2 ~ position, data = dta)`

But how can I check to see if the two measurements (`estimate1` and `estimate2`) were closer to each other for each row after making them both stand?